# Generating Strings with LeMP

Tags: c#, lemp, ec#

I'm trying to use LeMP to generate some C# bindings for a C++ library, and as part of this I need to generate a string that combines together some arguments from a LeMP macro to use in the DllImport EntryPoint value. Looking at the docs, it seems like a combination of concatId and stringify should do the job, but I can't get it to work. Here's a slightly simplified version of the code in question:

```
define TypedIndexer2D($CONTAINER_TYPE, $T1, $T2)
{
    replace(MethodName => concatId(Buffer, $CONTAINER_TYPE, GetExpr_, $T1, $T2));
    replace(CFunction => concatId(buffer_, $CONTAINER_TYPE, _getexpr__, $T1, $T2));

    [DllImport(Constants.LibName, EntryPoint = CFunction)]
public static extern IntPtr MethodName(IntPtr obj, IntPtr x, IntPtr y);
}

TypedIndexer2D(Int, Var, Var);
```

This emits the following:

```
[DllImport(Constants.LibName, EntryPoint = buffer_Int_getexpr__VarVar)] 
public static extern IntPtr BufferIntGetExpr_VarVar(IntPtr obj, IntPtr x, IntPtr y);
```

However, I need this:

```
[DllImport(Constants.LibName, EntryPoint = "buffer_Int_getexpr__VarVar")] 
public static extern IntPtr BufferIntGetExpr_VarVar(IntPtr obj, IntPtr x, IntPtr y);
```

(note the quoted EntryPoint).

I had thought that it would be something like the following:

```
replace(CFunction => stringify(concatId(buffer_, $CONTAINER_TYPE, _getexpr__, $T1, $T2)));
```

However that just emits the following:

```
[DllImport(Constants.LibName, EntryPoint = "concatId(buffer_, Int, _getexpr__, Var, Var)")]
```

How can I persuade LeMP to generate the string that I need here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is indeed to run `stringify` on the output of `concatId`, but there's a trick to it.

The difficulty is caused by execution order. Macros ordinarily run "outside-in", outermost macro first, in contrast to normal functions that run "inside-out". Therefore

```
stringify(concatId(Tea, ring, Cot, ton));
```

produces `"concatId(Tea, ring, Cot, ton)"`. There isn't a super elegant way to reverse the order yet - in custom `define` macros you can use a `[ProcessChildrenBefore]` attribute, but this doesn't let you to modify the existing behavior of `stringify`. Here's a technique that works:

```
replacePP(xx => concatId(Tea, ring, Cot, ton)) { stringify(xx); }
// Output: "TearingCotton";
```

in contrast to normal `replace`, `replacePP` preprocesses the match and replacement expressions, thus `concatId` happens before `stringify`. Applying this solution to your `TypedIndexer2D`, we get

```
define TypedIndexer2D($CONTAINER_TYPE, $T1, $T2)
{
    replace(MethodName => concatId(Buffer, $CONTAINER_TYPE, GetExpr_, $T1, $T2));
    replacePP(CFunction => concatId(buffer_, $CONTAINER_TYPE, _getexpr__, $T1, $T2));

    [DllImport(Constants.LibName, EntryPoint = stringify(CFunction))]
    public static extern IntPtr MethodName(IntPtr obj, IntPtr x, IntPtr y);
}
```